# Bash returns no such file or directory

Tags: string, bash, loops, substring, var

I'm facing an issue since yesterday, trying to search on the internet how to fix it... Without result.

There it is. This is my program :

```
OTHERDIR="/tech/gtr/scripts/osm/scan-configs"
filename="IDF-952584-SW1-126.110.84.253"
estdifferent=true;
if $estdifferent ; then 
    x=0;
    for fic in `find $OTHERDIR/liste/ -type f -name $filename*` ; do
    {
    echo $fic
    if [[$fic == *bak*]] 
    then
            filename_tab[x]=$fic
            ((x++))
    fi
    }
```

I want to check if $fic contains * bak * at the end

But the debug show me this when it arrives at the "if" instruction :

```
'[[/tech/gtr/scripts/osm/scan-configs/liste/IDF-952584-SW1-126.110.84.253_bak1' == '*bak*]]'

comparatif.sh: line 29: [[/tech/gtr/scripts/osm/scan-configs/liste/IDF-952584-SW1-126.110.84.253_bak1: No such file or directory
```

Why is it telling me "no such file or directory" ? I'm comparing a var and a regex.
(Line 29 is the IF $fic == * bak * instruction)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need spaces inside the comparison:

```
if [[ $fic == *bak* ]] 
     ^             ^
```

Instead of

```
if [[$fic == *bak*]]
```

Comment: Thanks for it. I've another problem with this code.

If i add echo "somethin" under the loop
The program is running the "for" loop for all the code, even the echo. is my syntax wrong ?

Comment: A `for` loop is executed from a `do` up to a `done`, so no need to `{`, just use that syntax. If you want further explanation, please update your question with current code.

Comment: Yup, i read the entire code, i had a "done" token useless. Thanks